# How does db link opens once we close it with DBMS_SESSION.CLOSE_DATABASE_LINK?

Tags: oracle11gr2

I am going to include in my stored procedure "the command to close the database link" after the link has been used, however, my question is whether the database link opens automatically the next time the proc is used?

Or do we again need to include some command to open the database link at the beginning of the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a DB link gets opened automatically upon each use of the DB link.